# Дублируются данные в массиве, получаемом из БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем привет, мне нужно изменить вид массива, получаемого от бд.

Код php:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dpk', 'user', '1234');
$db->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT entry_id, starred FROM `wp_wpforms_entries` WHERE form_id = 1656");

$query->execute();
$res = $query->fetchAll();
```

Переменная $res:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 106
            [0] => 106
            [starred] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 121
            [0] => 121
            [starred] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )
)
```

А нужно, чтобы переменная $res имела такой вид на выходе:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 106
            [starred] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 121
            [starred] => 0
        )
)
```

Т.е., насколько я знаю, этого можно добиться выставлением правильного параметра у prepare() или execute() или fetchAll(). В документации не разобрался и как это называется не знаю.

Comment: `$mode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`?

Comment: @Akina, это то, что я искал, спасибо.

Comment: Можете кстати написать ответ, я такого вопроса не смог найти

Comment: Но как по мне, то в данном случае гораздо кошернее будет PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR

Comment: @Ипатьев Тогда он получит `([106]=>0, [121]=>0)`, что ему вряд ли требуется...

Comment: @Akina с чего бы это вдруг ему не требуется гораздо более удобный формат? Словарь всегда удобнее списка даже при выводе, не говоря уже про поиск.

Comment: @Ипатьев Дык он же ж явно пишет, что нужно... ну и опять же - кто сказал, что `(form_id, entry_id)` уникально?

Comment: @Akina да откуда у вас у всех такая рабская психология-то?! Автор пишет "мне надо отстрелить себе ногу" - тут же целая орава берет под козырёк, и начинает рвать сухожилия, чтобы обслужить клиента по полной программе. Какая проблема предположить что заказчик сам не знает что ему нужно, и предложить альтернативный вариант? Я вообще не понимаю, с чем тут спорить. Я же не пишу "никаких FETCH_ASSOC!!!111адинадин". Я просто показываю еще один вариант, который может оказаться более удобным.

Comment: Ну и про неуникальный entry_id это совсем чушь. Если смотреть точки зрения здравого смысла, а не абстрактной математики

Comment: @Ипатьев *Я просто показываю еще один вариант, который может оказаться более удобным.* Ну так и пишите "Посмотрите ещё PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR - может, это вам больше подходит". А вот "в данном случае гораздо кошернее" - некорректно, потому что решает совсем другую задачу. *Ну и про неуникальный entry_id это совсем чушь.* да, вероятность, что `entry_id` уникален для каждого `form_id` - действительно велика, и здравый смысл требует именно этого. Но жизнь куда как богаче любой даже самой разнузданной фантазии, увы.

Comment: @Akina урок русского: "я считаю что так будет гораздо лучше(кошернее)" == "может, это вам больше подходит". Урок здравого смысла: ЕСЛИ мы выбираем из БД только entry_id, ТО при наличии дублей запрос не будет иметь смысла. Наличие дублей в выборке про которую автор "же ж явно пишет, что нужно" делает её бессмысленной. Если у вас претензии к выборке, то предъявляйте их автору вопроса.

Comment: @Ипатьев С уроком у Вас явно не задалось - фразы не эквивалентны. "я считаю что так будет гораздо лучше(кошернее)" однозначно подразумевает получение абсолютно того же, причём верного, результата, но более оптимальным путём. Тогда как "может, это вам больше подходит" этого вовсе даже не подразумевает.